# New Configure Kernel Crash in Linux

Tags: kernel

Is there any option in linux if first kernel is crash during boot time of system,  it will select automatically second kernel to boot the machine?

Thanks

Hanish

Answer (score 1):

There is not any option like this (as far as I know). It should be a kernel option and it should change the bootloader configuration but there are so many bootloader on different kind of device and it depends on the crash time. So, it is really difficult to implement a function like this.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is only a way to let it reboot the system in case of crash (i.e., through the **panic** parameter).

Supposing an embedded scenario, this behavior can be achieved through a boolean flag stored in Flash memory:

- The bootloader (e.g., U-Boot) keeps among its own variables a boolean flag set to true (e.g., try = true)
- The Linux filesystem, when succesfully booted, sets the boolean flag back to false
- The Linux kernel is booted with the **panic=0**   variable, which forces a reboot in case of crash (i.e., *panic*)
- U-Boot, when the flag is set to true (i.e., previous kernel boot had a failure) , boots a second version of the kernel